# Signalr 404 error after moving to iis7 server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, signalr, owin

I have a signalr service that is working fine on my development environment when hosted in IIS 8.

When the service is moved to our QA server using IIS 7.5, attempting to connect to my hub results in this error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
    Cache-Control: private
    Date: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 20:09:35 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Content-Length: 5307
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.<Then>b__17(Task`1 t)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3a.<RunTask>b__39(Task`1 t)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HttpClientException: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 20:09:35 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 5307
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__1(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass19`2.<Then>b__17(Task`1 t)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.TaskRunners`2.<>c__DisplayClass3a.<RunTask>b__39(Task`1 t)<---
```

My Startup class

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRStartup))]

  public class SignalRStartup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      app.MapSignalR("/restricted/signalr", new HubConfiguration());
    }
  }
```

And attempting to start a connection in the c# client

```
HubConnection foo = new HubConnection("http://localhost/ccwebdev/restricted");
foo.Start().Wait();
```

The QA server is running windows server 2008 r2 SP1, so it should have support for extensionless urls.

I also tried adding this to my web.config
    `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`

The app pools are in integrated mode, not classic mode

I have read many other similar SO posts and the troubleshooting guide for 404's here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting#other,
but with no luck.

Can anyone provide any other troubleshooting steps I can try?

---

EDIT

changing my map call to `app.MapSignalR("/restricted", new HubConfiguration());`
causes an exception to be thrown on service startup

```
[InvalidOperationException: Protocol error: Unknown transport.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context) +384
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext context) +502
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2 environment) +328
   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +611
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +208
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +434
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: I would suggest using app.MapSignalR("/restricted") or app.RunSignalR("/restricted/signalr"). MapSignalR appends "/signalr" for you. What is the url in `HubConnection foo = new HubConnection(url);`?

Comment: see updated url in edit

Comment: Did you change your call to MapSignalR? That could be your problem.

Comment: see my edit again, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This means that either "?transport=..." is not in the query string when making the /connect request. Or that transport is set to something other than "serverSentEvents", "foreverFrame" or "longPolling". You might get this error if you have "?transport=webSockets" since you are running 2008 r2 where WebSockets is not supported, but the .NET SignalR client should always use "?transport=serverSentEvents" or "?transport=longPolling" unless you did something like foo.Start(new WebSocketTransport()) which you shouldn't.

Comment: I fixed the error on my dev env by mapping to "restricted/push" instead. There are other urls that contain "../restricted/.." which signalr tried to process and threw the error. Still getting the same 404 error on the QA server though

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to manually patch the server for extensionless URLs? I'm not sure if server 2008 R2 SP1 includes that patch- you can give it a try and see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Comment: I checked here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=269, and that hotfix was listed as one of the fixes included in SP1